# Accessing dependent jars during evaluation/configuration stage

Tags: gradle

I am trying to extract a resource from a dependent jar file but it seems that I am missing something regarding the time when this code is evaluated.

I would like to do the following:

```
distributions {
  main {
    contents {
        into("etc") {
            from zipTree(configurations.runtime.filter { it.name.startsWith('myLib') }.singleFile)
            include "logback.xml"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

However on this I get:

```
A problem occurred evaluating script.
Expected configuration ':runtime' to contain exactly one file, however, it contains no files
```

Can this section be delayed to execution?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it is related to the execution order. The line

```
configurations.runtime.filter { it.name.startsWith('myLib') }
```

is not returning any results. Maybe you should try `configurations.runtime.files.filter ....`

Comment: I tried to move it to later, as an action in `installDist` and there it works as written above